# I want to use paoding.analysis.analyzer but I get errors

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

This is the errors in Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class   net.paoding.analysis.analyzer.PaodingAnalyzerBean overrides final method tokenStream.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Reader;)Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.examle.test.hello.main(hello.java:20)
```

Source:

```
package com.examle.test;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.util.AttributeImpl;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import net.paoding.analysis.analyzer.PaodingAnalyzer;
public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception{
        String content=null;
        Analyzer analyzer=new PaodingAnalyzer();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an API mismatch to me.

```
PaodingAnalyzerBean overrides final method tokenStream.
```

is a very clear error message, isn't it? `final` methods may not be overridden.

Any chance paoding requires a different version of Lucene? So that in the version you are using `tokenStream` is `final`, but in the proper version it was not `final`?